# Why getExternalFilesDir return null instead of throwing exception?

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) say:

> ***public File getExternalFilesDir (String type)***
>   ... Unlike `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`,
>   the directory returned here will be **automatically created** for you.
>   *Returns*
>   Returns **null** if external storage is not currently mounted ...

I use this method in a library and test it on devices with `maxSdkVersion="18"`. Before calling this method I'm sure that external storage is mounted (so, as document say, method should not return null).

Now I expect when user of library does not use  `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, method must throw exception,because it try to create a directory and App does not use write permission, but the method returns null yet. Why this happens?

Comment: Why is it that you expect an exception?  Is that behavior documented somewhere, or is that a standard behavior for performing an un-authorized action?   To shed more light on this, you can always step through the Android source.

Comment: @EJK When you try to create a directory on external storage without using permissions, it will cause exception.

Comment: OK.  I suspect that the distinction here is that creating a directory actually requires the permission, but calling "getExernalFilesDir", which does not alter the file system in any way is not an operation that needs to be blocked.  I agree it is weird that it returns null.  I would not have designed it that way.